# Oscilloscope-like chart software with trigger, but for saved time series (Linux)

Tags: data-visualization

I like to have a time series viewer, but like an oscilloscope providing a trigger and draw several intervals into the same plot. So to see outliers / different behavior in a  repeating signal, like the screen on a CRT scope or virtual scope modes on digital storage scopes would do.

Command line utilities would be ok.

Comment: Interesting question. I would imagine that Python together with a visualization toolset of your choice should allow to do that with only a few lines of code.